# Does every finitely generated dense subgroup of $ SU(n) $ contain a free subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, free-groups

I read in [On the spectral gap for finitely-generated subgroups of SU(2)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-007-0072-z) that every finitely generated dense subgroup of $ SU(2) $ contains a free subgroup.

Is it true in general that every finitely generated dense subgroup of $ SU(n) $ contains a free subgroup?

Comment: can the close vote explain how I can improve the question? Is there any additional context that you would like?

Comment: I did not downvote but by now you should be able to prove it yourself (for $n>1$). What is the key to the proof in the $SU(2)$ case? And you do not need finite generation.

Comment: No, the last paragraph is quite wrong: A typical intersection will be trivial.

Comment: @MoisheKohan oh ok well then I'll delete that then. So this seems not so easy to me, could you explain the argument? Honestly I'm not sure what the proof is like even in the SU(2) case.

Comment: Do you know the Tits' Alternative?

Comment: I've heard the name before! And I'm pretty sure I visited the wikipedia page once because it was mentioned in some MSE post but off hand I don'y know it, it's something like every subgroup of some sort of group is either virtually free or dense? That would just be me kind of guessing based off context here, let me just look it up. Update: just looked it up! I think I can write an answer now.

Comment: Very good. If you are interested in subgroups of Lie groups (and most of your questions are about these) the Tits' Alternative should be a part of your toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

This follows easily from the [Tits alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tits_alternative), as pointed out by Moishe Kohan.

Let $ G $ be a connected Lie group that is not solvable. Let $ \Gamma $ be a finitely generated dense subgroup of $ G $. Since $ G $ is not solvable and $ \Gamma $ is dense in $ G $ then $ \Gamma $ cannot be solvable or virtually solvable (a finite index subgroup of a dense group is still dense). So by the Tits alternative $ \Gamma $ must contain a nonabelian free group.

Comment: Right. One even proves existence of a dense rank 2 free subgroup, but this is more subtle.